# How to put multiline commands in ECS Task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, ecs-taskdefinition

I am trying to run a django application inside of a docker container (ECS - Fargate)

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to run multiple commands in the `Command` section of a task definition, currently it is configured like this

[image]

Howevery my containers keep on `STOPPING` and I cant even see the logs in CloudWatch

[image]

How do I get it to execute properly?, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I would do this by using `/bin/sh -c` despite the entry point:

```
/bin/sh -c "python manage.py ... <and the rest>"
```

This is also how it is done in the offical AWS ECS [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-service-discovery.html#create-service-discovery-cluster):

```
            "entryPoint": [
                "sh",
                "-c"
            ],
            "command": [
                "/bin/sh -c \"echo '<html> <head> <title>Amazon ECS Sample App</title> <style>body {margin-top: 40px; background-color: #333;} </style> </head><body> <div style=color:white;text-align:center> <h1>Amazon ECS Sample App</h1> <h2>Congratulations!</h2> <p>Your application is now running on a container in Amazon ECS.</p> </div></body></html>' >  /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html && httpd-foreground\""
            ]
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not solve the issue, My containers still stop

Comment: @malikbagwala in the screenshot I see there are `/n` characters. The example from aws and what I use do not use any new line characters. Maybe this is issue then?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me using a `aws ecs run-task` command.

```json
{
  "command": [
    "/bin/sh", "-c",
    "echo 'Hello' && echo ' alien ' && echo 'World'"
  ]
}
```

The command only has to be split for `bin/sh` and `-c` and the rest of the commands can be joined together with `&&`.

Comment: Minor typo. Index 0 of the command array should be "/bin/sh" instead of "bin/sh". Else you will encounter "exec bin/sh failed: No such file or directory". Other than that, this works.

Answer (score 2):

Made it with **&&** replacing spaces by commas, just like that:
[image]

```
touch,/usr/app/log/test1.txt,&&,touch,/usr/app/log/test2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following yaml in my AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition that works

```
          Command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - >-
                echo 'before: showmigrations --list'
                && python manage.py showmigrations --list
                && echo 'before: showmigrations --plan'
                && python manage.py showmigrations --plan
                && echo 'migrate'
                && python manage.py migrate
                && echo 'after: showmigrations --list'
                && python manage.py showmigrations --list
                && echo 'after: showmigrations --plan'
                && python manage.py showmigrations --plan
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with one of the services `rk-nginx`

This was the previous `nginx.conf`

```
upstream gunicorn {
    # docker will automatically resolve this to the correct address
    # because we use the same name as the service: "django"
    server django:8000;
}
```

However the `django` keyword gave me issues ( I think it was part of how ecs handles networks), I simply changed it to this

```
upstream gunicorn {
    server localhost:8000;
}
```